# Access violation error when creating pointer to pointer List

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++

i,m trying to create pointer to pointer List

`list<ObjectClass*> *lst_testList;`

and trying to use it this way

```
void FunctioningClass::functioningMethod()
{
    ObjectClass *object = new ObjectClass();
    object->i_testing = 234;
    lst_testList->push_back(object);
    object = lst_testList->front();
    cout<<object->i_testing;
    std::getchar();
}
```

I can build the program. But when i run it,it gives me this error.

Unhandled exception at 0x012885DA in ConsoleApplication7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

notice that when i create list like this

```
list<ObjectClass*> lst_testList;
```

and use it like this,

```
lst_testList.push_back(object);
```

it didn,t give me any error.

Comment: Is `lst_testList` dangled? I mean did you initialize it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such `list<ObjectClass*> lst_testList;` variable is [default-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).

For pointer `list<ObjectClass*>* lst_testList;` default initialization is not performed. Proper initialization for it is:

```
list<ObjectClass*>* lst_testList = new list<ObjectClass*>();
```

or

```
list<ObjectClass*>* lst_testList = NULL;
```

It depends on your goals.

Comment: Are there any advantages & disadvantages between two methods?

Comment: @YasithaBandara It's hard to say. It depends on architecture of your application (e.g. on `lst_testList` visibility). If it's global variable you can create single instance `new list<ObjectClass*>()` and use it over the application. If it's a field of `FunctioningClass` you can initialize `lst_testList` to `NULL` and create an instance `new list<ObjectClass*>()` later when it will be needed.

Comment: @YasithaBandara General approach is to always initialize pointers to some value. `NULL` will guarantee predictable behavior. It's easy to understand why pointer is `NULL`, but very hard to debug unpredictable behavior of [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Answer (score 3):

`list<ObjectClass*> *lst_testList` is a pointer to a list of ObjectClass pointers. In order to use it you either need to allocate it first or
(as you already found out) use`list<ObjectClass*> lst_testList` (which is a list to ObjectClass pointers) .